# Assign a value on OK button of JavaScript Alert Messagebox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I know that `confirm message-box` of JavaScript `can be assigned a value`. Now, i also want an alert `message-box (OK button) to have a value`, So that i can use it in my `server-side code in ASP.Net`.

Is this possible?

Comment: No click or any other event is there to capture when an alert box is closed, it just blocks the execution thread and display a message, so you cannot

Comment: @shadow—maybe the OP wants the "OK" button to have some other value, i.e. display something other than "OK". I really don't know.

Comment: @RobG alert message-box (OK button) to have a value

Comment: The default browser confirm dialog is completely implementation dependent (though HTML5 tries to [standardise it](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#dom-confirm) to some extent). You can't change the displayed button values (i.e. "OK" and "Cancel"), however you can construct your own dialog using DOM elements and script.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't understood well about the alertbox. 
In any javascript function if alert message is shown then after you click the ok button only next statement will get executed.

But if u really want to assign a value to ok button then just declare a variable and assign a value to that particular variable in your code after the alert code. Sample code will look like below.

```
function fnMyFunction(){ 
   var myval="";
   //your code goes here
   alert('Your Message');
   myval="your value";
}
```